# How to define tomcat-users.xml on embedded Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, selenium, junit

I'm using Selenium to run automatic JUnit tests on a Maven web application. Basically I'm running the application on an embedded Tomcat server (org.apache.tomcat.embed). The application uses BASIC authentication, so I need to somehow define tomcat-users.xml on the embedded tomcat server. I tried putting tomcat-users.xml to src/main/webapp/META-INF/ but it doesn't work.

Here's how I start the server:

```
tomcat = new Tomcat();
tomcat.setPort(0);
tomcat.addWebapp("/", new File("src/main/webapp/").getAbsolutePath());
tomcat.start();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured this out some time ago so here's the solution for someone who has a similar problem. Basically you can define the things that would be in tomcat-users.xml directly in the java code:

```
//Add role and user order is important
tomcat.addRole("userName", "admin");
tomcat.addRole("userName", "editor");
tomcat.addUser("userName", "password");
```

Comment: It seems that the order of `addUser` and `addRole` is important. Adding a role after adding the user didn't worked for me.
(Version 8.0.21)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by adding a context.xml file.

```
try {
     Context context = tomcat.addWebapp("/test", "PathToTheWebApp");
     context.setConfigFile(Paths.get("PathToTheContextFile").toUri().toURL());
} catch (ServletException e) {

}
```

Your context.xml should be like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
  <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MemoryRealm" pathname="PathToUsers.xml"/>
</Context>
```

Your users.xml file is similar to the tomcat-users.xml file.
Example:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tomcat-users>
    <role rolename="admin"/>
    <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="admin"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

Comment: should users.xml and context.xml reside inside the resources folder?

Comment: nope. You can give the path of the users.xml via pathname of the context.xml